# Regex - Matching String values and Date together

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string that looks like the following and am supposed to extract the key : value and i am using Regex for the same.

```
line ="Date : 20/20/20  Date1 : 15/15/15  Name : Hello World   Day : Month  Weekday : Monday" 


1) Extracting the key or attributes only.

   re.findall(r'\w+\s?(?=:)',line)
   #['Date ', 'Date1 ', 'Name ', 'Day ', 'Weekday ']

2)Extracting the dates only

   re.findall(r'(?<=:)\s?\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}',line)
   #[' 20/20/20', ' 15/15/15']

3)Extracting the strings perfectly but also some wrong format dates.

   re.findall(r'(?<=:)\s?\w+\s?\w+',line)
   # [' 20', ' 15', ' Hello World', ' Month', ' Monday']
```

But when I try to use the OR operator to pull both the strings and dates I get wrong output. I believe the piping has not worked properly.

```
re.findall(r'(?<=:)\s?\w+\s?\w+|\s?\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}',line)
# [' 20', ' 15', ' Hello World', ' Month', ' Monday']
```

Any help on the above command to extract both the dates (dd/mm/yy) format and the string values will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flip it around.

```
\s?\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}|(?<=:)\s?\w+\s?\w+
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/gWAXIm/1)

Regex will first try and match the first part. If it succeeds it will not try the next part. The reason it then *breaks* is because `\w` results in the first number of the date being matched. Since `/` isn't a `\w` (word character) it stops at that point.

Flipping it around makes it first try matching the date. If it doesn't match then it tries matching an *attribute*. Thus avoiding the problem.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gWAXIm/3 . We are doing a look behind scenario. But if keys are dates even those would get pulled when we flip in above scenario. Any workarounds for the same ?